# How do i change the attribute of a field in a ModelForm from views.py?

Tags: python, django

am currently working with Django1.7, and am working on a project which requires me to display a particular form field depending on a value. this is what have got.

**forms.py**

```
class ServiceForm(forms.ModelForm):
area = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Area.objects.all(), label=u'Area')

class Meta:
    model = Service
    fields = ['title', 'price', 'negotiable', 'location', 'phone', 'email', 'area', 'category', 'description',
              'image1', 'image2', 'image3', 'image4']
    widgets = {
        'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Service title e.g: Servicing of generators'}),
        'location': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Physical location of where the service will be rendered'}),
        'price': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'item price in figures e.g: 2000, 0 if free'}),
        'phone': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'seller\'s phone number (buyers can contact)'}),
        'email': forms.EmailInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'seller\'s email (buyers can contact)'}),
        'description': forms.Textarea(attrs={'placeholder':'Service description, a good and straight description attracts more interest', 'rows':'4'}),
    }

def save(self, commit=True):
    service = super(ServiceForm, self).save(commit=False)
    service.active = True
    if service.price == '':
        service.price = 0.0
    if commit:
        service.save()
    return service
```

is there a way i can change the property of attribute 'area' from my views.py ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to change?

Comment: yeah, i am trying to change the queryset of 'area' from my views.py

Comment: You can overwrite that in `__init__()` method of the form.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass 'area' to the form as a parameter and load the field queryset with it:

```
#form.py

class ServiceForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        area = kwargs.pop('area')
        super(ServiceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['area'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=area, label=u'Area')

    class Meta:
    ...

# view.py

service_form = ServiceForm(area=Group.objects.all())
```